# Form onsubmit not working with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using Ajax and Php to validate a user's login.. But form onsubmit is not working..

```
<form action="loggedin.php" onsubmit="return test()" method="post">
```

Javascript

```
function test(){
    var a = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("pwd").value;                
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        var resp = this.responseText;
        if(resp != "Correct"){
            document.getElementById("email").value = "";
            document.getElementById("pwd").value = "";
            document.getElementById("passdiv").style.display = "block";
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST","check.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send("email=" + a + "&passwd=" + b);
}
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: You're trying to prevent the form submitting by return a value from `onreadystatechange` and then capturing it in `onsubmit` … but the function you are calling from `onsubmit` is `test` and `test` doesn't have a `return` statement of its own.

Comment: @AnsBilal — No! Returning a value from a function defined by an intrinsic event attribute is how you prevent the default action for the event occurring. The link you provide doesn't seem relevent either.

Comment: then it should return some value

Comment: @AnsBilal — Yes, and my earlier comment explains why the OP (presumably) thinks it should and why it doesn't.

Comment: @Quentin As you said that test does not have its return of its own, on updating it as in the code, it is still not working

Comment: @Handmadegiftsco — Your edit just puts more return statements inside the `onreadystatechange` function. `test` still doesn't have one of its own.

Comment: @Quentin Okay.. Just got my mistake..Thanks..

Answer (score -1):

```
onsubmit="test()"
```

Don't use `return`.

Comment: If you don't return anything from `onsubmit`, then the regular form submission will happen. Your suggestion will make the problem **worse**.

Comment: Still not working after removing return